# Automatic retries with Ribbon (without zuul): not working + wrong documentation?

Tags: java, spring, load-balancing, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

In the latest versions of spring cloud Netflix's official documentation (for example [2.0.2.RELEASE, the last GA version](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.0.2.RELEASE/multi/multi_retrying-failed-requests.html)) it states:

> When Spring Retry is present, load-balanced RestTemplates, Feign, and Zuul automatically retry any failed requests (assuming your configuration allows doing so).

But that seems wrong concerning the use of standalone Ribbon (i.e. load-balanced RestTemplates). I couldn't make it work nor found any working example. Moreover, I found other sources stating quite the opposite was true, such as:

- [spring-cloud with RestTemplate//Ribbon/Eureka - retry when server not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468697/spring-cloud-with-resttemplate-ribbon-eureka-retry-when-server-not-available)
- [Spring Cloud - Getting Retry Working In RestTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765049/spring-cloud-getting-retry-working-in-resttemplate)).

So, it's the documentation wrong or is the whole world missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the same issue; Zuul will neither retry nor failover to alternative servers in the ribbon server list using the default (Apache Http Client) configuration. We tracked it down to [this line of code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/v2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/apache/RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java#L95) in the `RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` class:

```
@Override
public RequestSpecificRetryHandler getRequestSpecificRetryHandler(
        RibbonApacheHttpRequest request, IClientConfig requestConfig) {
    return new RequestSpecificRetryHandler(false, false, RetryHandler.DEFAULT,
            requestConfig);
}
```

The hardcoded `false, false` parameters effectively disable retry from ever happening. It is easy to fix this.

Add this to your Zuul main application class:

```
@RibbonClients(
    defaultConfiguration = {EurekaRibbonClientConfiguration.class,
        MyRibbonConfiguration.class})
```

Create a class, `MyRibbonConfiguration` and use it to emulate the `ribbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` method [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/v2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/apache/HttpClientRibbonConfiguration.java#L121) except we override and fix the `getRequestSpecificRetryHandler` method that's causing problems.

```
public class MyRibbonConfiguration {

  @RibbonClientName
  private String name = "client";

  @Bean
  public RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient ribbonLoadBalancingHttpClient(
      IClientConfig config, ServerIntrospector serverIntrospector,
      ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, RetryHandler retryHandler, CloseableHttpClient httpClient) {

    RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient client =
        new RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient(httpClient, config, serverIntrospector) {
          @Override
          public RequestSpecificRetryHandler getRequestSpecificRetryHandler(
              RibbonApacheHttpRequest request, IClientConfig requestConfig) {
            return new RequestSpecificRetryHandler(true, true, RetryHandler.DEFAULT,
                requestConfig);
          }
        };

    client.setLoadBalancer(loadBalancer);
    client.setRetryHandler(retryHandler);

    Monitors.registerObject("Client_" + this.name, client);
    return client;
  }
}
```

Adjust `true, true` to reference from properties if you want. With this in place Zuul will start respecting the `ribbon.MaxAutoRetries` and `ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer` properties.

Note that if you are using Ribbon with Feign for server->server calls then those Feign calls are not affected because OpenFeign hardcodes those two parameters to `true, true`.